# Streaminsight vs CDC

Tags: reporting-services, ssis, ssas, streaminsight

Am I missing something, or is streaminsight an easier way to incorporate the traditional BI solution with SSAS/SSRS/SSIS.

Traditional:

```
Sources->SSIS->Staging area->SSIS->warehouse->SSAS/SSRS/PowerPivot/..
```

StreamInsight:

```
Sources->StreamInsight->SSAS/SSRS/PowerPivot
```

In the traditional way we do not have capabilities for real-time analytics, you always need to define a time period to run the SSIS package again. We can however, use CDC (Change Data Capture), which makes it somewhat realtime. CDC checks for changes in databases and fires the SSIS package.

StreamInsight offers a real-time ETL solution.

Is this right?

Comment: What is "real-time" What is the acceptable amount of latency allowed? How long does your cube processing take? CDC tracks the changes but it doesn't fire off any ETL processing. It simply provides a reference marker for you to track changes and it imposes a not-insignificant burden on the database itself to track those changes. SSAS can't use StreamInsight as a data source -> [Supported sources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492165.aspx) Nor could it use Apache Storm or any other low latency engines

Comment: Latency: i'd say about 1 minute. How long does the cube processing take: no idea, does it make a difference? It's a hypothetical question. CDC: you are so right. If SSAS can't use StreamInsight, what does it use for analyses? Is it build-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is certainly *one* use case for StreamInsight. This is especially true if you have cases where you can take advantage of the stream processing to glean intelligence from the data while it's *in flight* to the warehouse.